# What does "serial upvoting reversed" mean?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, serial-voting

In my reputation history I see that I lost 75 points of reputation because of "serial upvoting reversed."  What does that mean?

It seems that this question was asked in passing in [this discussion](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1616/mathoverflow-20-final-sandbox-testing) and sort of answered by Asaf Karagila, but I didn't understand his answer.

Comment: Tea seems to be [down at the moment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4438), so I'll add at least a [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20151102061434/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1616/mathoverflow-20-final-sandbox-testing/) to the discussion mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Basically, there are systems in place that prevent serial voting. For example, someone may find one or two of your answers as really good and upvote a whole bunch of others without reading<sup>1</sup>. On the other hand, a malicious user may give you many downvotes.  Such strings of serial upvoting or downvoting in short time intervals get reversed within 24 hours.

<sup>1. On SE we vote on the basis of the merit of the *post*, not the *user* (though the merit of the user can be a factor). Blindly upvoting a user's post goes against this.</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is allowed to base your voting decisions not exclusively on a post.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Sure. However, the advice is to vote on the basis of the merit of a post (of course, the merit of the user makes it more reliable and contributes). I guess this isn't exactly a "rules" thing, so I'll edit that. Thing is, "I like this user so let me blindly upvote all his posts" is not allowed.

Comment: @Manishearth Sure, I was thinking more something along the lines "Haven't I told this user already three times that you can't divide by zero?".

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Oh, yeah, that. That's different, that's when the merit of the user is so bad it overshadows the post :P It happens too often.