# Tea archive (mathoverflow.tqft.net) seems to be down

Tags: bug, tea

It seems that the link http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/ (which, according to [this announcement](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3960/tea-mathoverflow-net-deprecated), serves as an archive of [the old tea](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/tea/info), i.e. the previous incarnation of MathOverflow Meta) no longer works.

It does not seem to be just my local problem - I have tried to check using [Geopeeker](https://geopeeker.com/fetch/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathoverflow.tqft.net%2F) and [Down for Everyone or Just Me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mathoverflow.tqft.net).

While the site is down, the content might be accessible from the [HTML dump posted by Scott Morrison](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3960/tea-mathoverflow-net-deprecated) and probably some of the content using the "usual methods" such as Google Cache or Wayback Machine.

EDIT: I have extracted files from the dump created by Scott Morrison and put them [on my website](http://msleziak.com/mathoverflow/). I do not make any guarantees for how long this copy will be available. (And if, for some reason, MathOverflow moderators prefer to remove this copy, I will do so.)

EDIT2: I should have mentioned that there is a redirect from tea. mathoverflow.net to mathoverflow.tqft.net - as mentioned by Scott Morrison in the [comments to this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3960/tea-mathoverflow-net-deprecated/3964#3964). Of course, if there are some old links around, the redirect does not help *at the moment* - while the copy at the tqft.net domain is not available.

Comment: Is there any news on this?  I just tried to visit http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/918/request-for-discussion-how-much-tragedy-is-appropriate-for-mathoverflow , with no luck.  (As suggested [elsewhere](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4438/tea-archive-mathoverflow-tqft-net-seems-to-be-down#comment21602_4459), the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150426081014/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/918/request-for-discussion-how-much-tragedy-is-appropriate-for-mathoverflow) can help, but it would still be nice to know if tea is simply gone.)

Comment: @LSpice This link works too (at the moment) as mentioned above: https://msleziak.com/mathoverflow/tea/discussion/918/request-for-discussion-how-much-tragedy-is-appropriate-for-mathoverflow/ I have [asked one of the moderators about this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=56600186#56600186). Based on the response I got there, I would not expect any change soon.

Comment: Just to add some examples to the redirect mentioned in "EDIT 2": 
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/918/request-for-discussion-how-much-tragedy-is-appropriate-for-mathoverflow redirects to http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/918/request-for-discussion-how-much-tragedy-is-appropriate-for-mathoverflow and 
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/965/oldest-joint-paper redirects to
http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/965/oldest-joint-paper - in both cases you land of a page which gives an error.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, lovely. I would very much like to get a working link to Yemon Choi's thread on a serial cheat,

http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1187/extending-from-a-plane-in-r3-again-and-again-and-again

simply because some idiot is beginning  similar behavior on MSE. I put an MSE meta question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31270/anything-to-be-done-about-this-cyclic-self-deletionmodifyre-post

Comment: The specific thread that you linked seems to be available in the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20190726171926/http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1187/extending-from-a-plane-in-r3-again-and-again-and-again/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20170201224732/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1187/extending-from-a-plane-in-r3-again-and-again-and-again/

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, I did not notice this for about a month. The second one worked and I bookmarked it. I'll try the other one too. Also works, appears to wind up at the same place.