# Serial voting was reversed

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

I was recently noticed "serial voting was reversed" on MO. I am curious about how this works, and what this exactly means (I don't have the feeling that I did something wrong).

Note that I don't care about the loss of reputation. I'd rather like to understand what I did wrong, in order not to repeat it.

Comment: I think that if you have seen that in your reputation tab, you can click on "learn more" to get to the [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/serial-voting-reversed). And you can find links with some basic information in the [corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/serial-voting/info).)

Comment: You can check an older post on this meta: [What does "serial upvoting reversed" mean?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/300) (Although I am not sure whether this one can be considered an exact duplicate - since this question seems to be mostly about the question: "Did I do something wrong?" Most probably, the answer is no, nothing.)

Comment: I have not looked into this properly, but it's possible that this will happen more often than usual for a little while, in relation to [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379788/upcoming-cleanup-of-duplicated-votes?cb=1)?

Comment: If you did something wrong, you'd have gotten a personal notice saying so, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: It seems I lost 70 in reputation from this correction.  Probably from errors going back to the beginning of MO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It pretty much coincides with my reputation reversal of one vote on another site in the network. Normal serial voting reversals happen around 3am UTC, and I asked about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379854/295232) - the response I got from staff pretty much proves [@TimCaption's guess](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5378/serial-voting-was-reversed#comment27436_5378) is right. This was someone who, completely by accident, managed to upvote a post of yours twice, and that mistake has been reversed now. It's extremely likely nobody did something wrong here.

Comment: I thought it is impossible to upvote a post twice. Most likely, somebody liked one post, looked for other posts by the same person, liked these as well and upvoted quickly (say, more than 5 different posts). The software decided that this was a serial upvote and cancelled all these upvotes.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Please do read the post linked from the answer. It was indeed possible to vote twice under some circumstances due to a bug.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I see, so it was a bug present in the system from the onset.